# R C Stack allocation

Tags: r, stack, stack-memory

I have a script in which I loop over >1k csv files, merge them and save the merge another csv file.

```
#Loading libraries
library("dplyr")
library("data.table")

#loop over my files
for(i in seq(1,1000))
{
    file <- read.csv(paste0("/my/path/", filesList[i]), stringsAsFactors=FALSE, row.names=NULL)

if(exists("merge")){

    merge <- bind_rows(merge, file)

}else {
    merge <- file
}

}
#Save the merged files
write.csv(merge, file="/path/merge.csv")
```

I get the following errors:

```
Error: memory exhausted (limit reached?)
Error: segfault from C stack overflow
Error: C stack usage  140736289161248 is too close to the limit
```

FYI, just before writing to csv `gc` returns

```
>           used  (Mb) gc trigger  (Mb) max used  (Mb)

>Ncells   504073  27.0     940480  50.3   750400  40.1

>Vcells 32397836 247.2   83331575 635.8 83281289 635.4
```

I allocated 2 GB of RAM to R and limited stack size to 1M.

**My question is in two parts:**

1. Is there a general RAM/Stack ratio I should follow when limiting memory usage? (ex: for each 1GB of RAM you should have 1M stack)
2. Is there a better way to write my code when facing such situation? (Ex: directly appending each `file` to the `merged.csv` file and then loading the `merged.csv`)

Comment: Where is `bind_rows` defined? It doesn't look like you are actually `merge`ing data.frames. Would all data.frames fit into RAM? If so, you should read all files into a list of data.frames and use `data.table:::rbindlist`.

Comment: Why do you limit RAM (to such a low amount)?

Comment: What is the average size of the csvs? Each csv has how many rows and columns?

Comment: @Roland I am using `dplyr::bind_rows(y, z)` I am on a webserver that has unfortunately limited RAM. What amount of RAM would you suggest to run R? Could you expend on your `data.table:::rbindlist` suggestion?

Comment: @Frash each csv is about 830kb with about 10k rows. In total, it's about 85MB of csv files

Comment: Typical and efficient work flow is `rbindlist(lapply(list.files(path = ..., pattern = ...), fread))`, but that assumes that all files fit into RAM.

Comment: @Roland the files take about 85MB on the disk but I am not sure how this is going to be translated once loaded in R. I could give it a try

Comment: That size should be no problem. It's nothing.

Comment: Try this one: `filelist = list.files('/my/path/', full.names = T); do.call(rbind, lapply(filelist , read.csv))`. IF this works or R throws out of memory error.

Comment: @Roland, works well with `full.names=T`

Comment: @Frash it worked well